# Anchoring CSS Repeating Background Image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a webpage with a header banner in the following configuration:

```
<---Repeating Image Left--><---Banner Image---><---Repeating Image Right--->
```

The page is designed with fixed width content, but the banner spans the entire width of the browser window (thus the reason for including repeating images on the left and right).

The two repeating images are different and they are also not standard background images which can be positioned where-ever. Instead, the left image needs to be anchored/stuck to the left-hand side of the banner image and then repeat itself leftwards, from that point, as the browser window is expanded. Likewise, the right image needs to be anchored/stuck to the right-hand side of the banner image and repeat itself rightwards from that point.

Using the pure `background-image:` property with the `repeat-x` set does not work, as the image will be repeated/tiled from the left-hand side of the browser window, rather than from the left/right hand side of the banner image outwards in the desired direction.

Any help to achieve the desired effect would be appreciated.

Comment: can u post the result images ........

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I cannot post the images as they are for a project which is not yet live.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single styled element, yes:

```
#banner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50%; margin: 0; padding-right: 50%;
  background-image:url('banner.png'), url('left-bg.png'), url('right-bg.png');
  background-clip: padding-box, content-box, content-box;  
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box, content-box, padding-box; 
  background-origin: padding-box, content-box, padding-box;
  background-position: center, right, center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x, repeat-x;
}
```

The element has three backgrounds. The trick is in getting different ones to appear on the left and right, which I've done by adding 50% padding on the left. The left hand side is "padding box" and the right is "content box".

You might want to make the first background an `<img>` so you can give it a title tag -- if you do then it'll appear only in the right-hand 50% of the window so you'll have to left align it and use `position:relative; left:-250px` to get it back into the middle.

Lastly, the background images are locked to the middle of the window, not the edge of the banner, but you can fix that by changing the images themselves.

Comment: Just a heads up, I tried it but you accidentally made the 3rd choice on `background-clip` **content** instead of **padding**. I also made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swCwd/2/embedded/result/) of your example with above correction. But great answer. Posting a fiddle is always nice so the asker can view it, and you can catch bugs ;)

Comment: Thanks for this answer - almost exactly what I need. However, the last remaining issue is the locking of the background images. You mention that "the background images are locked to the middle of the window, not the edge of the banner, but you can fix that by changing the images themselves.". I am unsure what you mean about how I should modify the images - could you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: I mean, if the middle image is 250px wide, the left image is locked 125px to the right of its edge, and if the image is 50px wide then it's effectively 25px out. If you design the image so the middle, rather than the edge, lines up with the banner then nobody will notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a URL to check the site? It sounds like you'll need to experiment with the css property:

```
background-position {x, y}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As per my comment above, the website is not yet live as it is still being developed and not ready for publication.

Answer (score -1):

```
banner
{
background-image:url('image.gif');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center; /*optional*/
}
```

i don't know if this works, but it's worth a try.