# HTML table: keep center aligned, regardless of browser width

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is a follow-on from a previous SO question [Anchoring CSS Repeating Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260986/anchoring-css-repeating-background-image) but sufficiently different to treat as a separate question.

The jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/By2xj/ demonstrates the concept. I have a banner image (center) which then requires repeating images on the left and right which will display and repeat depending on the width of the browser window. The proviso is that the left and right images must be locked to the edge of the center banner image. You can see this effect if you expand the jsFiddle Result window - the left and right repeating images always remain locked to the side of the center banner image and expand out from that point.

So all this is working, but I have used a table to achieve this effect, as the CSS suggested in the previous Stack Overflow question didn't fully work and was a bit browser dependant, particularly not playing with older browsers.

With this table based solution, I would like to always keep the centre banner image centered, even when the browser width is smaller than the banner. If you reduce the size of the jsFiddle Result window you will see that when the browser width is smaller than the banner, the banner sticks to left-alignment rather than being centered.

So my question is how can I always keep the center banner center aligned (or perhaps, more correctly, the entire table center aligned), even when the browser width is smaller than the banner width (and containing table cell)?

Comment: Is the banner only an image? You can set it to a `background-image`: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/YgJh9/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit cheat but, I hope what you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/By2xj/8/

what's happening is, I'm creating a div in that middle cell, and position absolute, after that, centering it to screen. that div will remain centered all times, regardless size of the browser window.

for the record:

```
<table id="banner-table">
    <td id="left-image"></td>
    <td id="center-image"><div></div></td>
    <td id="right-image"></td>
</table>​
```

css:

```
 #banner-table {

    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#left-image {
    background-image: url(http://www.dummyimage.com/100x200/ff0303/ffffff.png&text=Left);
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#center-image {

    width:400px;


}
#center-image div {
    top:0; left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;

    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(http://www.dummyimage.com/400x200/0021fa/ffffff.png&text=Center);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#right-image {
    background-image: url(http://www.dummyimage.com/100x200/1f9900/ffffff.png&text=Right);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;}​
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great and works exactly as required. One bit of strangeness though - on my actual page (not the jsFiddle) depending on the width of the browser window there is a 1 or 2 pixel gap between the center graphic edge and the left and/or right repeating graphics. I guess it has got something to do with putting the graphic into a `div` instead of the `td` itself. Any ideas?

Comment: Scratch that, my fault. Just had to adjust the width of the `td` :)

Answer (score 1):

You could ditch the tables and go with something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bryandowning/f2unW/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the left graphic is no longer locked to the right-hand side of the center graphic. However, if you do have any other table-less suggestions I would certainly welcome them :)

Comment: Thanks for the update :) I was really hoping this would do the job, but unfortunately there is one major issue that wasn't apparent from my jsFiddle. In your implementation the left and right backgrounds tile under the center banner - I can't have this happen, they need to start from the left and right edges of the banner respectively. This jsFiddle shows the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/cCEEV/ . I don't suppose there's a way around this? :)

Comment: Sure, all you need to do is modify the `background-position` property. I updated the fiddle again. Instead of `left` and `right` use, `-200px 0px` for the left and `200px 0px` for the right.

Comment: Thanks for the update Bryan, but now the left is no longer locked to the left-side of the center graphic. Also, the right side (and presumably, the left side too) only appears to be working because the dimensions of the graphics are such that it can tile twice underneath the center graphic before appearing like it is locked to the side of the center graphic. The dimensions of the actual graphics are quite different and won't allow this to happen - the left and right graphics actually need to start on the sides of the center graphic.

Comment: Did you try it with your graphics? It should work fine regardless of the complexity of the repeating graphic. Change the `background-position` values to something not divisible by 100 and you'll see what I mean. That's why I made the center graphic half transparent. Unless I'm completely missing something here.

Comment: Hi Bryan. I think we are talking at cross-purposes. By of example, the left edge of the banner is designed to sit up against the right edge of the left repeating graphic, as the two graphics mesh together. That's why they need to sit adjacent, rather than repeat underneath the center graphic and then emerge at some point. Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your HTML code like as:

```
<table id="banner-table">
    <td id="left-image"></td>
    <td id="center-image"><div></div></td>
    <td id="right-image"></td>
</table>​
```

first you can implement this without any CSS file.Then you can customize your code as your requirement.